# ControlSend to send key input to Notepad window

Tags: window, autohotkey, notepad

```
 ControlSend, Notepad, {b down}{b up}, Untitled - Notepad
```

I want to send `b` key input to Notepad window (so that b key would be pressed, when Notepad's window is not active).

No error, no feedback, nothing happens. I found out Notepad's class by using Window Explorer program and the title is the default unsaved document's. What am I doing wrong here? I was trying to find something working that would help solve this problem, but there isn't so much information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing Class and ClassNN. 
[ControlSend](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) requires ClassNN as the second parameter

Notepads default ClassNN is Edit1.

```
ControlSend, Edit1, {b down}{b up}, Untitled - Notepad
```

Comment: that's great, works! what do you suggest to use to find out ClassNN?

Comment: The built-in `Windows Spy`.

Comment: yes, I found it now. Tried to make it work with Microsoft Word, which has ClassNN _WwG1, but doesn't seem to send input. any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @decas No, comments aren't made for asking new questions. Use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask